# Saving data on android APP

Tags: android, save

Hello I'm working on app android which notices the scores of a card's game.
I'm looking for how to save the actual scores and teams' name when the app getting destroyed or stopped to find them when i open it again.

```
public class ShowScore extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences save = null;

private TextView nameTeam1= null;
private TextView nameTeam2= null;

private TextView scoreTeam1 = null;
private TextView scoreTeam2 = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_score);

    nameTeam1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1);
    nameTeam2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team2);
    scoreTeam1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
    scoreTeam2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);

    nameTeam1.setText(save.getString("Team1","Team 1"));
    nameTeam2.setText(save.getString("Team2","Team 2"));
    scoreTeam1.setText(String.valueOf(save.getInt("Score1", 0)));
    scoreTeam2.setText(String.valueOf(save.getInt("Score2", 0)));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
    save = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();

    editor.putString("Team1", nameTeam1.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Team2", nameTeam2.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("Score1", Integer.parseInt(scoreTeam1.getText().toString()));
    editor.putInt("Score2", Integer.parseInt(scoreTeam2.getText().toString()));

    editor.commit();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** It is fixed i should add
    save = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Into the onCreate().

Comment: Either use local SQLite database or SharedPreferences. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Additionally I would suggest using Room Persistance as detailed in Android documentation

Answer (score 0):

Recently i started investing in sqlite database, just purely because it stays on the system, and is further exportable. but a great tutorial i followed was 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

This has all the C.R.U.D for database application.

Comment: Thank you i'll take a look at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try many options if data is small and just variables then you can try shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

just like that and value will be stored
and for retriving data then you need just

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
```

Comment: I dont want to use an sqlite database, i just have to save 2 int and 2 String,

Comment: For what u posted on which method i use it ? onStop() ?

Comment: so use first one sharedpreferece it  will be suitable for your use case

Comment: I put it on the onStop() methode of my activity ?

Comment: yes you can use it onStop() but best way is use it onPause() and call it onResume()